# mySQL SELECT upcoming birthdays

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write a query to select users of a database whose birthdays are in the next 7 days.

I've done a lot of research but I can't come up with a working solution.

The birthday field is stored as a varchar eg '04/16/93' is there any way to work with this?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `PERSONS` 
WHERE  `BIRTHDAY` > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

I should have made it more clear, I'm trying to find birthdays not dates of birth. So i'm just looking for days and months not years.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To get all birthdays in next 7 days, add the year difference between the date of birth and today to the date of birth and then find if it falls within next seven days.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(birthday, 
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birthday),1,0)
                YEAR)  
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

If you want to exclude today's birthdays just change `>` to `>=`

```
SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(birthday, 
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) >= DAYOFYEAR(birthday),1,0)
                YEAR)  
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);

-- Same as above query with another way to exclude today's birthdays 
SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(birthday, 
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birthday),1,0)
                YEAR) 
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
     AND DATE_ADD(birthday, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday) YEAR) <> CURDATE();


-- Same as above query with another way to exclude today's birthdays 
SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(birthday, 
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birthday),1,0)
                YEAR) 
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
     AND (MONTH(birthday) <> MONTH(CURDATE()) OR DAY(birthday) <> DAY(CURDATE()));
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d8769/11) of all queries

Comment: The first query would only return newborns, the 2nd would return only people born in the future....

Comment: @GoatCO  duh! looking at the question and the query OP provided, I just assumed that current year birthday is stored in the table. Anyway, updated answer. Hope that works.

Comment: Right i've another problem I didn't realise. Birthday is stored as a varchar eg '04/16/1993' any way to work with this?

Comment: @DannyWalsh As you have figured out already, you need to convert the string to date format using `STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y')` and use this in place of `birthday` in the above query.

Comment: If you run this script on December 31 and the birthday is january 1 this script won't work.

Comment: fixed by adding 1 based on the day of the year. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that this solution too has problems with leap years (cf. my example in commtn to Todor's answer). The common problem is that `DAYOFYEAR` of birthdays in March-December differs between leap and non-leap years

Comment: worked for me thanks.But stuck on ordering them, any thought on that?

Comment: @FarhanSahibole, do `ORDER BY MONTH(birthday), DAY(birthday)` to get the birthdays in order.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this, today, 2020-07-28. A birthday on 1951-07-28 is not being included. It's the `+ IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birthday),1,0)` part that is pushing the comparison year for the birthday to 2021, so it's not included in the `BETWEEN` statement.  Thoughts?

Comment: this answer is incorrect; see Tom McQuarrie's answer (or https://stackoverflow.com/a/72864336 which orders the birthdays).  any approach involving dayofyear or deciding how many years to add within date_add is going to have corner cases that don't work.

Answer (score 13):

Its very easy and simple. No need to use any if conditions or anything else you just need to use DATE_FORMAT() function of mysql.

Here is my sql query that is

```
SELECT id,email ,dob FROM `users` where DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') and DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT((NOW() + INTERVAL +7 DAY), '%m-%d')
```

---

Comment: This doesn't actually work when you try to get future birthdays on the next year.

Answer (score 6):

This is my solution. It also works if date of birth is January 1st and today's date is December 31.

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `dateofbirth`,
    DATE_ADD(
        dateofbirth, 
        INTERVAL IF(DAYOFYEAR(dateofbirth) >= DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()),
            YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dateofbirth),
            YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dateofbirth)+1
        ) YEAR
    ) AS `next_birthday`
FROM `user` 
WHERE 
    `dateofbirth` IS NOT NULL
HAVING 
    `next_birthday` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY `next_birthday`
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: I'm afraid this goes wrong if the year of birth is a leap year and the current is not or vice versa: dateofbirth = 2000-07-04, curdate = 2015-07-05 calculates next_birthday as 2015-07-04 instead of 2016-07-04 (which does not harm for the query about next week); but dateofbirth = 2001-07-04, curdate = 2016-07-04 leads to next_birthday = 2016-07-04 instead of 2015-07-04

Comment: Good catch @HagenvonEitzen I will try to provide a fix for that.

Answer (score 6):

Any solution using DAYOFYEAR() will be flawed when the date of birth occurred during a leap year.  Consider using TIMESTAMPDIFF() when working with age or birthdays.

Current age can be calculated as

```
timestampdiff(YEAR, person.date_of_birth, curdate())
```

Calculate the upcoming birthday by adding the age to their date of birth.

```
DATE_ADD(
    person.date_of_birth, 
    INTERVAL timestampdiff(YEAR, person.date_of_birth, curdate())+1 YEAR
)
```

Putting this together to solve the OP’s query

```
select
    DATE_ADD(
        person.date_of_birth, 
        INTERVAL timestampdiff(YEAR, date_add(person.date_of_birth,INTERVAL 1 DAY), curdate())+1 YEAR
    ) upcoming_birthday
from person
having upcoming_birthday between curdate() and DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Notice that I have added one day to date_of_birth when calculating age, otherwise today’s birthdays would not be returned.

Comment: This is the only correct answer I've seen. The rest do not work across year boundaries, leap years, etc.

Comment: You a genius, most of the functions used here are not on w3schools

Answer (score 5):

I did a lot "researches" and here is my solution, I guess it is very easy to understand!

```
SELECT *,
(366 + DAYOFYEAR(birth_date) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW())) % 366 as left_days
FROM `profile`
ORDER BY left_days;
```

Comment: Sometimes this returns yesterdays birthdays as 0 left_days :-(

Answer (score 3):

I found this code to work really well:

```
DATE_ADD(user_birthdate, INTERVAL YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), user_birthdate)-1)) + 1 YEAR) AS next_birthday
```

it actually really simple, it calculate the person age, then the current's year birthday and then add 1 year.

it based on the answer of Robert Eisele which you may find here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

p.s.

with this solution you might fetch people who had a birthday yesterday (that's because the -1 in the FROM_DAYS calculation, but it is needed because of the leap years). this shouldn't consider you too much since you only want 7 days a head so you should just add the following condition:

```
HAVING next_birthday BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 Select * From persons
 where (DayOfYear(birthday) >= 7 
         And DayOfYear(birthday) - DayOfYear(curdate()) Between 0 and 6) Or
       (MOD(YEAR(curDate()),4) = 0) And MOD(YEAR(curDate()),100) != 0
        And (DayOfYear(birthday) + 366 - DayOfYear(curdate())) % 366 < 7) Or
         (DayOfYear(birthday) + 365 - DayOfYear(curdate())) % 365 < 7)
```

Comment: Fixing Leap year issue n now

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working with this query. Due mostly to the help of Lobo's answer.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y')) YEAR) 
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: see the updated answer. There was a defect which has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer above from Lobo is flawed in that, if the query is run on December 31, and the user has a birthday on January 1, they will not be matched.

You must add logic to the query so that, if the birthday has already passed this year, you look at NEXT YEAR's birthday, not this year's.  Details below:

```
SELECT *, IF( DAYOFYEAR( STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y') ) < DAYOFYEAR( NOW() ),
DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL YEAR( CURDATE() ) - YEAR( STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y') ) + 1 YEAR ),
DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL YEAR( CURDATE() ) - YEAR( STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y') ) YEAR ) )
AS nextBirthday FROM persons
WHERE nextBirthday BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

While trying to get the list who have their b'days upcoming in a range of time, we can run in to couple of issues.

When there is a leap year, then there is a chance that the condition you have fails to handle the case of leap years. Next problem could be like today is `2016-12-30` and you need b'days for next 7 days. So the end of the period is in year `2017`. Some condition fail in this case. These are very important test cases.

Most of the fixed in this thread are using the `DAYOFYEAR()` which fails when you are on a leap year.

eg.

`DAYOFYEAR('2016-03-01 00:00:00')` is **`61`**.
`DAYOFYEAR('2015-03-01 00:00:00')` is **`60`**

Simplest and most easy to understand way is this.

1. Calculate the next upcoming b'day for a user.
2. Then check if the day comes in our range.

This works on leap years and also the range of dates span in two years.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `PERSONS` 
WHERE  
    /* 
       Here we calculate the next coming b'day for user 
       and check if it is between our span 
    */
    CONCAT(IF( 
            CONCAT( YEAR(CURDATE()), substring(`BIRTHDAY`, 5, length(`BIRTHDAY`))) < CURDATE(), 
            YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1, /* Adds an year if already past */
            YEAR(CURDATE())  /* Use this year if it is upcoming */
         ), substring(`BIRTHDAY`, 5, length(`BIRTHDAY`))) 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @tot DAY)
```

PS: Also it is the best solution if you want to order these on the basis of the b'days. You just need to add this as a field.

Comment: `DAYOFYEAR` worked for me. You made my day and save my life, thanks dear :)

Answer (score 1):

We've had troubles with a calendar that had to show the next ten birthdays (including todays birthdays).
I've reduced the solution I just found to the relevant parts:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, birth_date,
    IF (DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'1980-%m-%d %T')) < DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'1980-%m-%d %T')) ,
          DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'1980-%m-%d %T'))+368 ,
          DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'1980-%m-%d %T'))) AS upcomming
FROM users
WHERE birth_date IS NOT NULL AND birth_date !=0
ORDER BY upcomming ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

It sets every year (including the actual) to a leap year, so there won't be any problems with that.
If you get close to the end of the year it's no problem, too.
I'm quite statisfied to finally finding a working solution, so I wanted to share this, maybe it is of use for someone else :)

P.S.: If you don't want to show todays birthdays, just add a `+1` after `DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'1980-%m-%d %T'))`

Comment: This idea is genius! @Fanmade Why "368"?  Why " %T" ?

Comment: Instead of next 10, I needed to show all upcoming birthdays in next 7 days or past 2 days.
`SELECT user_id,full_name,dob, 
IF (DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'1980-%m-%d')) < DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'1980-%m-%d')) - 7,
          DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'1980-%m-%d'))+366,
          DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'1980-%m-%d'))) - DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'1980-%m-%d')) AS dist
FROM users u
WHERE dob IS NOT NULL HAVING (dist BETWEEN -2 AND 30)
ORDER BY dist<0 ASC, CASE WHEN dist<0 THEN -dist ELSE dist END ASC`

Comment: Oh god, this was four years ago, I switched jobs twice since then and I don't even remember that I have given this answer^^
Apart from that, the "%T" is indeed unnecessary and the "368" was just typed in rather randomly, "366" should be better, while still factoring the leap year in. 
Your solution does seem rather complicated to me. What about this way?

Comment: `SELECT user_id, full_name, dob,
    IF (DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'1980-%m-%d %T')) < (DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'1980-%m-%d %T'))-2) ,
          DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'1980-%m-%d %T'))+366 ,
          DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'1980-%m-%d %T'))) AS dist
FROM users
WHERE dob IS NOT NULL 
AND dob !=0 
HAVING dist < (DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'1980-%m-%d %T'))+7)
ORDER BY dist ASC;`

Comment: Checking your code again, it does make sense if you want to split your result in before and after dates, while still having the data to be able to sort in any way you like. Now I do like your result more that mine (and it does even look simpler than my way).
Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did when I faced the same problem :

```
select * from users 
where ( month(date_of_birth) > month(CURDATE()) 
 and month(date_of_birth) < month(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),30)) ) 
 or ( month(CURDATE()) = month(date_of_birth) and day(date_of_birth) >= day(CURDATE()) 
 or month(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),30)) = month(date_of_birth) and day(date_of_birth) <= day(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),30)) ) 
 or ( year(CURDATE()) > year(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),30)) and month(date_of_birth) < month(CURDATE()) and month(date_of_birth) > month(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),30)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is optimized solution for leap year problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d') ), '%Y-%m-%d')
     BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from persons as p
WHERE   
MOD( DAYOFYEAR(p.bday) - DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) + 366, 366)  
BETWEEN 0 and 7  
ORDER by DAYOFYEAR(p.bday) ASC
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Lobo's answer to tackle leap years

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DATE_ADD(dob,INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob)
  + IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) > MONTH(dob), 1,
     IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(dob) AND DAY(CURDATE()) > DAY(dob), 1, 0))
       YEAR)
        BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

So another approach you can take is to do a little more work before hitting the database layer. For example, I recently did this in a Laravel (PHP) and Postgres project. I basically built up an array of dates (ie. the next 7 days), and did a `where in` query to find users with birthdays on those dates.

```
User::whereNotNull('birth_date')
    ->where('birth_date', '<=', $endDate)
    ->whereIn(DB::raw("to_char(birth_date, 'MMDD')"), Carbon::range($startDate, $endDate)->map(function ($date) {
        return $date->format('md');
    }))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple PHP Code & SQL Query to retrieve upcoming birthdays. Where date of birth is stored as DATE (YYYY-MM-DD Format). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrF7M.jpg)

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'paasword', 'databasename');
$nod = 5;     //Number of days upto which you want to retrieve birthdays
$delim = $filter = "";
for($i=0;$i<$nod;$i++){
    $date = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
    date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("$i days"));
    $filter .= $delim."'".date_format($date,"m-d")."'";
    $delim = ", ";
}
$sql = "SELECT NAME, DOB, MOBILE, EMAIL, TITLE FROM tablename WHERE SUBSTR(DOB,6) IN ($filter) ORDER BY SUBSTR(DOB,6) ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    
$i=0;
echo '
<table class="table-1 mt-2 table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>S. No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>MOBILE</th>
    </tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $i++;
    $dob = date('Y-').date_format(date_create($row["DOB"]),'m-d');
    $day = date_format(date_create($dob),'w');
    switch ($day){
        case 0:
            $day = "Sunday"; break;
        case 1:
            $day = "Monday"; break;
        case 2:
            $day = "Tuesday"; break;
        case 3:
            $day = "Wednesday"; break;
        case 4:
            $day = "Thursday"; break;
        case 5:
            $day = "Friday"; break;
        case 6:
            $day = "Saturday"; break;
    }
    echo"
    <tr>
        <td>".$i."</td>
        <td>".$row["NAME"]."</td>
        <td>".date_format(date_create($row["DOB"]),'d-m-Y')." $day</td>
        <td>".$row["MOBILE"]."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
echo"
</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution may be more easy.

Create query string, something like, (I am using PHP and MySql)

```
$query = "SELECT cols FROM table WHERE MONTH(DobCol)= ".date('m')." AND (DAY(DobCol) >= ".date('d')." AND DAY(DobCol) <= ".(date('d')+$NumOfDaysToCheck).")";
```

Then execute this $query.