# How get birthday with an interval, around New Year

Tags: mysql

On my website I have an overview of all birthdays, from 7 days back up to 7 days forward from the current day.

This is my good working query:

```
SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%m-%d') as date_order
FROM employees
WHERE  DATE_ADD(birthday, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday) YEAR) 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY date_order ASC
```

But it goes wrong the last days in december and the first days of January.
How can I change this query, so I get a list like this:

**Birthdays:**

- 2016/12/28: John
- 2016/12/30: (current day) Ali
- 2016/12/31: Mike
- 2017/01/04: Mark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL SELECT upcoming birthdays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747853/mysql-select-upcoming-birthdays)

Comment: Why `INTERVAL 200 DAY`

Comment: I know that topic, but in that topic there is the same problem at December/January