# How to search birthdays dates using only day and month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, date

I've been looking for a solution here in the community, but I have not found anything specific. I need to do searches for birthdays among a period using only the month and month day (excluding year). I have users with their birthdays registered in date fields in my MySQL.

**`Name      |  Dt. Birth`**
`Julian    | 1990/01/18`
`Luiz      | 2000/02/15`
`Morgana   | 1973/02/01`

I need to realize two different tasks.

> **1st** - Let's suppose today date is February 01. How could I take today's date and decrease 14 days, searching for users whose birthday was on previous 2 weeks? (only Julian would be listed). 
>   Another query will list users whose birthday is today (only Morgana would be listed). 
>   And a third one should list the birthdays within next two weeks (only Luiz would be listed) 
>   I was using these code, but they don't seem to work at all times.

```
select * from user where DAYOFYEAR(dateBirth) between DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-14 and DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-1;
select * from user where DAYOFYEAR(dateBirth) = DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE());
select * from user where DAYOFYEAR(dateBirth) between DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())+1 and DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())+14;
```

> **2nd** - In a form, I will select two days and months
>   `|01||January |`
> `|15||February|`
> and the users whose birthday is within this range will be listed. (All users listed)

Maybe this fiddle help you visualize the question. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dec7a/5

I reproduce the above queries that show some inaccuracy. If you change values (-14/+14 and (-1/+1), you shall be able to list the users.

Comment: store dates as [dates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html), in mysql, this will make your life infinitely easier

Comment: They are date fields

Comment: ` 01/02/1973` that's not the mysql format of  'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: this is what i think you are going for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747853/mysql-select-upcoming-birthdays

Comment: @smith Sorry, corrected, I wrote it wrong

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: Your queries seem fine. What's the problem here?

Comment: These queries take the day of year to make the comparison, at some times, It list users out of right range (1 day more, or 1 day less). Some relation with leap years maybe?

Comment: Then please make a reproducible example. http://sqlfiddle.com would be a great help.

Comment: I think three questions is too broad.

Comment: Actually It is only one question: How to use only day and month to make queries by period.

Comment: Try SUBSTRING_INDEX or month() and day().

Comment: Create a new table field with `DATE` type, where you save birthdays with same year for all records. Date calculation would be much easier + field index could be used...

Comment: @Glavić I have more than 1k users on my database, this solution could be great, but it is no longer viable.

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo: 1k is nothing :) You don't even need indexes for that :) Just use DATE_FORMAT() or SUBSTRING() :))

Comment: @Glavić So you are suggesting me to add a new field or use these functions on my queries?

Comment: @revo I created the fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dec7a/5

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo: I will always recommend solution what will use indexes...

Comment: @Glavić I don't actually know how to use this. I had never used, and I didn't know until now. Could you elaborate some guide that corresponds to my problem?