# Finding birthdays in next 30 Days using day, month and no year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains birthday date in 3 columns, as `bday_day`, `bday_month` and `bday_year`, With `birth_year` `nullable`.

I have to write a query to find the upcoming next month birthdays, Even if the `birth_year` is `null`. (With **December** to **January** cases to be taken care)

I have tried the answer given below but got No luck as it is calculated based on `year`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748008/4694871

Edit: I have updated the question from birthdays next month to birthdays in the next 30 days.

Update:
Here is what I have tried( with the **December** to **January** cases ), Suggestions are welcome..

```
SELECT to_date(CONCAT(date_part('year',current_date), '-', bday_month, '-',bday_day), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS birthdate

FROM  users u2 
WHERE (date(to_date(CONCAT(date_part('year',current_date), '-', bday_month, '-',bday_day), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
+ 
interval '1 year' * CASE when(DATE_PART('doy',to_date(CONCAT(date_part('year',current_date), '-', bday_month, '-',bday_day), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
< DATE_PART('doy',current_date)) then 1 else 0 end))
            BETWEEN current_date AND date(current_date + INTERVAL '30 day')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck" ? The linked answer has mysql tag, which may not work with postgresql.

Comment: What does "next month" mean exactly? Today is June 26, so "next month" means July? Or do you want the whole of July plus the remaining days of June? Or 30 days from today? Or 31?

Comment: The lesson to be learned: store dates as date, not as separate {year,month,day} fields.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have edited the question for more understanding.

Comment: @wildplasser Agreed. But Sometimes devs have to bear other's sins :)

Comment: @shahkalpeshp Yeah. I took that solution as inspiration. Both SQL or PgSQL solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Birthdays in the next 30 days:

```
SELECT * FROM yourt_able
WHERE to_date(lpad(bday_day::text,2,'0')||
              lpad(bday_month::text,2,'0')||
              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE),'DDMMYYYY') <= CURRENT_DATE+30
ORDER BY bday_day;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0adc2a7ea7827d258bb5b20cc16ef006)

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the answer...can you suggest how can I do it for the next 30 days?

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn check my last edit (demo 2)

Comment: Tried it. but I guess this will fail for people with birthdays in Jan?

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn I don't get it. It returns records containing dates within the next 30 days. Have you tested it?

Comment: Abhishek saharn is right, this will fail for birthdays in January, because in December you will have to look for birthdays in January next year, while you compare with January this year and thus dismiss these dates.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you're totally right, thanks for pointing out. +1 I was hopping to get this answer from the OP. Sometimes we hear from users "will your solution work?" without even trying it out :-D so yes, your solution looks better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

The joy of adequate `DATE` columns (if you don't have them: convert into `date`s first):

---

```
\i tmp.sql

WITH j (bday_day, bday_month,bday_year) AS (
  VALUES (25,07,NULL),(25,08,NULL),(03,07,2001)
)
, fudge AS (
SELECT *
        , make_date(coalesce(j.bday_year,2000) , bday_month, bday_day) AS zdate
        , make_date(2021 , bday_month, bday_day) AS this_years_birthday
        , now()::date as today
FROM j
        )
select * from fudge
-- WHERE this_years_birthday BETWEEN today AND today+ '30 days':: interval

WHERE this_years_birthday BETWEEN today AND today+ '1 mon':: interval  ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
 bday_day | bday_month | bday_year |   zdate    | this_years_birthday |   today    
----------+------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+------------
        3 |          7 |      2001 | 2001-07-03 | 2021-07-03          | 2021-06-24
(1 row)
```

---

Note: this will fail in December. (left as an exercise for the reader ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it like this: A person's next birthday is either this year or next year. Use the two years hence to build the date.

```
with this_year_and_next_year(name, birthday) as
(
  select name, make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, bday_month, bday_day) from users
  union all
  select name, make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int + 1, bday_month, bday_day) from users
)
select name, birthday
from this_year_and_next_year
where birthday between current_date and current_date + interval '30 days'
order by birthday;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just extract next month from current date then compare it with bday_month column. Year is not necessary. Then to find the exact date you can use `make_date()`

```
<!-- -->
 create table birthdates (bday_day int , bday_month int,  bday_year int);
 insert into birthdates values(25,6,2021);
 insert into birthdates values(30,6,null);
 insert into birthdates values(29,7,2021);
 insert into birthdates values(2,7,null);
 insert into birthdates values(24,7,2000);
 insert into birthdates values(4,8,null);
```

Query#1 (find the birthdates within next month)

```
 select *,
 make_date(cast(extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)as int),bday_month,bday_day)birthdate
 from birthdates
 where (case cast(extract (month from current_date) as int) when 12 then
 1 else cast(extract (month from current_date) as int)+1 end)=bday_month
```

Output:

| bday_day | bday_month | bday_year | birthdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 7 | 2021 | 2021-07-29 |
| 2 | 7 | null | 2021-07-02 |
| 24 | 7 | 2000 | 2021-07-24 |

Query#2 (find the birthdates within the next 30 days)

```
 select *,
 make_date(cast(extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)as int),bday_month,bday_day)birthdate
 from birthdates
 where make_date(cast(extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)as int),bday_month,bday_day)>current_date
 and make_date(cast(extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)as int),bday_month,bday_day)<=current_date + INTERVAL '30 day';
```

Output:

| bday_day | bday_month | bday_year | birthdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 6 | 2021 | 2021-06-25 |
| 30 | 6 | null | 2021-06-30 |
| 2 | 7 | null | 2021-07-02 |
| 24 | 7 | 2000 | 2021-07-24 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=05c27b33b5245b0d0aabf3f02b03dc5a)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer... It would be helpful If you can suggest how can I do it for the next 30 days?

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn I have added another answer to do that.