# Query upcoming birthdays with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table:

```
+-------------------+
| name | birthday   |
|-------------------|
| A    | 1972-04-24 |
| B    | 1994-12-27 |
| C    | 1974-11-11 |
| D    | 2003-07-23 |
| E    | 1968-01-06 |
| F    | 1977-01-28 |
| G    | 1986-06-06 |
+------|------------+
```

I want to query for the results of the next 3 birthdays from today regardless of the year (LIMIT 3).
I use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(birthday, INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday)) YEAR)) > $doy_today ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(birthday) ASC LIMIT 3
```

($doy_today is day-of-year today)

It seems to works fine except for some days end of the year.
For example today is 2021-12-25, the result is:

```
1/ 12-27 B
```

instead of

```
1/ 12-27 B
2/ 01-06 E
3/ 01-28 F
```

I know that dayofyear of Dec-31 is the greatest so there won't be a bigger dayofyear. How can I fix it, or someone show me another way
Thank you very much

Comment: how do you want to handle people with Feb 29 birthdays if it is currently a non-leap year?

Answer (score 1):

Someone's next birthday on or after today (treating people who have a Feb 29th birthday as having the 28th in a non-leap year) is:

```
case
    when birthday + interval year(current_date) - year(birthday) year < current_date then
       birthday + interval year(current_date) + 1 - year(birthday) year
    else
       birthday + interval year(current_date) - year(birthday) year
end
```

You just need to select that and order by it; trying to order by dayofyear is not going to be helpful.

```
select
    name,
    case
        when birthday + interval year(current_date) - year(birthday) year < current_date then
           birthday + interval year(current_date) + 1 - year(birthday) year
        else
           birthday + interval year(current_date) - year(birthday) year
    end next_birthday
from `table`
order by next_birthday, name
limit 3
```

Comment: @ ysth, Do you have a method to query for SQL understand that after Dec 31 is Jan 1? (ignore year)

Comment: @bin2003 the expression I give gives a full date of a person's _next birthday_, which you can sort by.  so 2023-01-01 will be after 2022-12-31.  If you need the date formatted, go ahead and select a formatted version, but order by the unformatted date.

Comment: added a full query

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this by taking the difference in days between today and the birthday.  Then, use the modulus 365 to figure out which 3 people have the nearest birthday.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(NOW(), TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday) - 1, birthday) % 365
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: I have the feeling leap days are going to make that have some strange corner cases

Comment: February 29th is a problem for certain.  At least, my answer always places the birthday at least one year before the current year, which partially fixes things.

Comment: and I don't see how that deals with the end of year problem (for people who's birthday this year is already past, looking at their birthday next year)

Comment: @ysth Well just using plain mod 365 is even more wrong, as the leap year error accumulates over the decades since a person's birthday.  We could normalize a leap year going by the OP's preference.

Comment: I mean the problem is how to mysql understand that after 12/31 is 1/1