# How to sort a list of birthdays in the format ‘%m-%d’ to find the closest dates to today?

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb

For my Python application, I store birthdays in a database in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` with the year (`yyyy`) always being 2020 so I allow the leap year date Feb. 29, this system has worked fine for me. I just get the month + day from the database and ignore the year. However, now I want to make a function that returns upcoming birthdays.

I've tried a simple SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT user_id, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') AS upcoming_birthday 
FROM birthdays 
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(birthday) > DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND guild_id = %s 
ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(birthday);
```

But this doesn't take the "year switch" into account, e.g. if today's date is December 15 and the next birthday is in January it won't return anything because the DAYOFTHEYEAR is smaller.

How would I make a SQL query or Python function that always returns the next birthdays accurately?

Comment: If the birthday is in the next year, then you always want to include it.  So add `YEAR(birthday) > YEAR(NOW())` as an OR condition.  i.e. `WHERE (YEAR(birthday) > YEAR(NOW()) OR DAYOFYEAR(birthday) > DAYOFYEAR(NOW()))`

Comment: If `birthday` is in the format `"%m-%d-2020"` the surely none of the builtin date/time functions will work as that is not a valid date format

Comment: As suggested by @RiggsFolly you should only ever store dates as `Date` or `DateTime` types. Using the proper types means that you can always get valid comparisons between them.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the format isn't actually that, it's "%m-%d-%Y", however in my python code I always use 2020 because to store birthdays, the year doesn't matter & I want to allow february 29, which isn't possible in all years. Edit: it's stored in MariaDB as DATETIME

Comment: you need to define what you mean by upcoming.  You clearly want January to be considered "upcoming" on December 15th.  You probably don't want December 14th to be considered "upcoming" on December 15th.

Comment: That also is not a standard date format. only `yyyy-mm-dd` is valid. In order to be processable by a machine dates have to be stored in a logical format. Starting in the middle and working outwards is not logical

Comment: "yyyy-mm-dd" is correct, sorry I'm confusing it with my Python code. However my point is that I always use 2020 for "yyyy" since only the month and day matters. With upcoming I mean any date that comes after today's, in order of which is the closest to today.

Comment: Python has nothing to do with this question, thats why I remove that tag!

Comment: You say find the closest, find upcoming.  Define what you mean, some number of birthdays? Some period of time?  Your attempt returns all the rows in the table, albeit sorted, it doesn't find anything.  Define the results you actually want and the problem is trivial

Comment: Store dates using the proper data type `DATE`. Storing them as string is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Gotta love everybody missing the point and marking answers as dups. This site is such a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer presumes that all birthdays are stored with all years of birth replaced by any fixed year that includes a leap year. It is not intended for use beyond that purpose.

Create a ranking relative to the current date. A bit of modular arithmetic handles the negative numbers/wrap-around. Leap-day birthdays will sort between February 28 and March 1 regardless of the upcoming year:

```
SELECT user_id, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') AS upcoming_birthday 
FROM birthdays 
WHERE guild_id = %s 
ORDER BY (DAYOFYEAR(birthday) - DAYOFYEAR(now()) + 366) % 366;
```

Depending on the observation of the leap-day anniversary, which was not specified, if you wanted to look for birthdays within a certain number of days you might want to offset February 29 by one so that it logically falls within the range ending February 28. And since this method of counting always allows for a day 29 at the end of February it isn't actually computing the number of days until the next birthday unless the non-leap adjustment is made for dates March 1 and beyond.

Comment: "Leap-day birthdays will sort between February 28 and March 1 " - they really should be treated the same as Feb 28 for non-leap years.  This makes a difference if there are additional order by criteria.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72864336 for a better way.

Comment: with all the birth years stored as 2000, that's the only problem with this answer, but if people's actual birth dates are stored, someone born 2004-03-31 could appear before someone born 2003-04-01, since their dayofyear is equal.

Comment: @ysth There are no DOBs stored. All the years are saved as 2020. So all the days of year are computed as during a leap year. That comment is irrelevant. I don't assume OP's requirements regarding other than what I noted. Some applications may need to treat March 1 as the logical anniversary.

Comment: right, but I can easily see someone copying this answer in a case where there are stored birth years.

Answer (score 0):

Without schema and sample data it's hard to give you an exact solution. There may be a more elegant approach but something like this should work:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birthday) AS years_ago,
CASE
    WHEN eta + INTERVAL (SELECT birthday) YEAR < CURDATE() THEN birthday + INTERVAL ((SELECT years_ago) + 1) YEAR
    ELSE birthday + INTERVAL (SELECT years_ago) YEAR
END AS upcoming_birthday
FROM birthdays
ORDER BY upcoming_birthday
```

Basically, get the birthday in the current year and if it's before today, add one year.

Comment: This won't handle the leap days once the date has moved into March. It might be slightly ok to merge those with another date, but won't that error?

Comment: @shawnt00 - That's true but not really outlined in the scope of this question.  If the OP wants to clearly define what should happen in case of a leap birthday we can address it, but otherwise my assumption is that it should be celebrated within the current year.

Comment: I think it's clearly addressed that OP has leap day birthdays and wants to keep them. Beyond that, an error is not going to be acceptable regardless.

Comment: @shawnt00 - It wouldn't be an error imo. "*I want to make a function that returns upcoming birthdays.*".  If Feb 29th is returned, it's still an upcoming birthday regardless of whether or not that date exists in the current year. Ask anyone with a birthday on a leap year.  The OP has not mentioned anything specific in regards to what should happen in this case other than that they want it returned. If the OP needs Feb 29th converted to Feb 28th or March 1st or not returned at all, that can be easily addressed, but I believe my answer offers enough of a start here.

Comment: Your logic generates February 29 in non leap years. That's will cause execution errors (unless Maria automatically translates those to March 1.)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood, what errors specifically are you referring to?

Comment: @shawnt00 - there is no scenario I'm aware of where that would happen. The DBMS wouldn't validate leap days in this case as we're only selecting a string and sorting it.

Comment: When you add one year won't there be an implicit cast to a date type? Having generated a bogus leap day date (as string) I believe that will fail. It would at least succeed by using a static year rather than prepending the current one. The output of `case` is probably still string but possibly Maria also converts the `else` to a date as well depending on type precedences. Admittedly, I don't know it's behavior.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know if that will work as an implicit cast. I would test I'm Maria if I could. But the problem isn't where it lands, it's where it started from. That fiddle returns null with the start year of 2025. (Most systems I'm familiar with would have errored there.)

Comment: @shawnt00 - I see what you mean.  Thanks for pointing this out - I've made an edit that I believe solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question, but in Python, you can do it this way. I tested it, and it returns the dates sorted, ignoring the year.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

birthdays = ['12-31', '01-02', '03-25', '12-20']

def find_birthdays(birthdays):
    dateTimeNow = datetime.now()
    formatted_today = dateTimeNow.strftime('%m-%d')
    year = dateTimeNow.year

    def dateDifference(birthday):
        birthday_this_year = datetime.strptime(f'{year}-{birthday}', '%Y-%m-%d')
        if birthday_this_year < dateTimeNow:
            birthday_this_year = datetime.strptime(f'{year+1}-{birthday}', '%Y-%m-%d')
        return (birthday_this_year - dateTimeNow).days

    upcominBirthdays = sorted(birthdays, key=lambda x: dateDifference(x))

    return upcominBirthdays

upcominBirthdays = find_birthdays(birthdays)
print(upcominBirthdays)
```

Comment: Still gotta be careful with leap days.